# Printer - can't access through Centreware Internet Services

Tags: internet, ip, services, network-printer

We have three network printers (Xerox WC 7125). We also have YSoft SafeQ installed on our server (we add new printer for our users by always entering the same IP - server's). Two of printers are fine, but we have a problem with the last one.

On this printer, I've been playing with some settings for enabling network scanning and scanning to PC. I enabled SSL, so I've been accessing printer's Centreware Internet Services with:

```
https://'IP printer3'
```

For SSL, I've also installed some (imaginary) certificate.

Then I discovered some other (easier) way to also enable network scanning and scanning to PC, and consequently disabled SSL. Since then, I can't access printer's Centreware Internet Services (with `http://'IP'`) - error HTTP 404.

I've enabled SSL back through user interface on printer and I could access Centreware Internet Services with:

```
https://'IP printer3'
```

Then I uninstalled certificate for SSl, disable SSL and now there is no way I can access Centreware Internet Services.

Printer (also scanning) is working normally and I can also ping it through cmd.

Comment: duplicate http://serverfault.com/questions/398172/printer-cant-acces-through-centreware-internet-services

Comment: OK, I found out a solution: Port (for http - TCP/IP) was set to 21, so I've changed it on printer's user interface to 80 and voila, it's working! Regards

Comment: Answer your own question if you can, please, using the button below (in about 7 hours).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found out a solution: Port (for http - TCP/IP) was set to 21, so I've changed it on printer's user interface to 80 and voila, it's working! Regards